# Did the badges get reset?

Tags: discussion, badges

Did all of the badges get reset? Does this happen yearly or is a function of the switchover from Chiphacker? Honestly, I don't care about the badges themselves, just wondering if it's a bug or if I should not flip out this time next year as well.

Seriously, I don't care about the badges.

"Badges? Badges??? We don't need no STEEEKIN badges!"

(sorry, had to be done)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In meta your badges are a separate entity. I received all of my badges on the parent site.

Are you missing yours? I looked on your account and you seem to have badges from answers you gave on the chiphacker site.

Comment: Yeah, I'm an idiot, sorry. That's exactly what it was. We can close this if we need to.

Comment: I actually can see others finding this issue and seeing this question. You want to accept my answer?